# Post Picture + description in my facebook fun page from my website?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload one picture + description in my facebook fun page from my website(backOffice of the website) i didn't find one clear exemple to use i tried many scripts but i got many errors i need help here is my code :

```
    function postOnFacebook($app_id, $app_secret, $message, $icon) {
        require 'src/base_facebook.php';
        require 'src/facebook.php';

        $curlcontent = "curl";
        $curlstatus = "Curl is not installed  - This is a Problem";
        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
            $curlcontent = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $curlstatus = "Curl is available but cannot access Facebook - This is a problem ";
            if (strlen($curlcontent) > 6) {
                $curlstatus = "Curl is available and can access Facebook - All is OK";
            }
        }

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId' => $app_id,
                    'secret' => $app_secret,
                    'fileUpload' => true,

                ));

        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        $photo_details = array(
            'message' => 'Photo message',
            'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()

        );    


            $file = $icon; //Example image file
            $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
            $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

BUT i got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebookSender\src\base_facebook.php on line 1039
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I made a change to your question because I don't think you should disclose your app id and your app secret here, in case you were wondering why the change..

Comment: Thanks mishu but i already change it :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload photos using curl that way, on this line:

```
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . $file;
```

you need to provide a path, not an url.

Comment: if the file is not on your server you can download it first, provide the path to curl, and delete it after..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use an image which is not local to send in your request. You need to download the file locally to send it in your request.

Since curl is looking for the image locally the file "http://www.sudoku-gratuit.fr/illusion-optique/1image-illusion-optique18.jpg" will not be found.